# Is automating the withdraw of a NFT smart contract a good idea?

Tags: nft, erc-721, smart-contract-wallets, openzeppelin-contracts

Just wondering out ! Something like automatic withdraw after every 24 hours or something like withdraw after every mint on the contract.

If its a good idea, sharing any ways or resources for me to do it out would be helpful !

Would love to hear your perspectives on this !!

Comment: what does withdraw mean? after mint, the NFT should belongs to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that by "withdraw" you mean transferring the minting revenue to the owner. An automatic withdraw every 24 hours isnt possible. Smart contracts can't do anything automatically. Doing that after every mint is a bad idea, as it makes your mint function more expensive for no real reason. Transferring ether costs 21k gas no matter what the quantity transferred is, so with a transfer to the owner at the end of every mint, you're charging the user 21k gas more on each mint, and if you have a normal withdraw function for the owner, you'll just be paying 21k gas once to transfer all the contracts balance

Comment: Thanks ! One question ... Its a bit stupid one  
does smart contract have any crypto holding limits ?

Comment: Nop, unless you code one in

Answer (score 0):

you cannot automatize the withdrawal just by writing solidity code because smart contracts execute code only in reaction of an external event.
If someone calls it, it reacts and executes some code.
But it is not able to execute code by itself.

What you can do is creating a python/js script which calls the withdraw function, + a job commmand which is calling the script every 24h.

The script has to know the mnemonic or the private key of an address, because it needs to sign a transaction on the blockchain, so be carefull on what you do. Do not give to the script a mnemonic of your real wallet, just create a wallet for this purpose.

What I would do is:

- creating a whitelist function into the smart contract where the owner can add/remove managers from it (and the owner would add the script wallet as a manager)
- creating the script by giving to it a mnemonic never used elsewere
- whitelisting the script wallet into the smart contract
- Limiting the withdrawal function to only the owner of the contract and the whitelisted manager(s) and sending the eth not to the caller but to a treasurer address that only the owner can change

About the other question, as perfectly said by Foxxxey, it would be a waste of fees

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the call with Chainlink Keepers and schedule the withdrawal of the amount to the owner's account.

However, there is a principle called, **PULL OVER PUSH** in solidity. It says never send money to the owner's account, instead allow them to withdraw.

Comment: here is a link you can read more: https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/pull_over_push.html